# Use translations in php not twig, symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, translation, twig

I am writing an app in Symfony2 using FOSUserBundle. However, all of their templates are in Twig, but I prefer to use php templates instead.

Using the translate file, they use this:

```
{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}
```

which corresponds to this section

```
security:
    login:
        username: "Username:"
        password: "Password:"
        remember_me: Remember me
        submit: Login
```

in the translation file. How would I write this in php?

Comment: did you even try to search before asking? There is a section in the docs that's called ["translation in templates using php"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#php-templates)

Comment: I actually tried this, however it just prints out what I put in brackets. For example:

$this->get('translator')->trans('username')

Gives me : username. Not "Username: "

Also, I tried putting: security.login:username as suggested, but that didn't work either. So that's why I am asking what the proper syntax is.

Comment: if the yaml you posted correctly reflects your translation file then the key you should be using is: login.username.

Comment: but that yaml is weong, because the twig example is correct

Comment: when the code was posted on here, it somehow ate my spaces before Login and the children. Like i mentioned before, it works fine with twig. It's just the php that just prints out the contents of the brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you recognize the special name of the translations file in the FOSUserBundle? It's `FOSUserBundle.en.yml' for example. The filename follows the [message domains](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#using-message-domains) convention. Look further in the bundles templates and you see, they using the message domain:

```
{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

So you have to use the same message domain with the translator service in php:

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('security.login.username', array(), 'FOSUserBundle');
```

In a PHP template it sould look similar.

```
<?php echo $view['translator']->trans('security.login.username', array(), 'FOSUserBundle') ?>
```

The default message domain is `messages` and can be ommited if you get the translations from eg a `messages.en.yml` file. But every other domain must be given to the translator. By the way, translations for validators must be in eg a `validators.en.yml` file.

Comment: Dependency Injection tag is `@translator.default` by Symfony 2.6, the `@translator` tag refers to LoggingTranslator now. So `$this->get('translator')->trans(...` is `$this->get('translator.default')->trans(...` by Symfony 2.6